# Jailbreak for iOS 5.0.1

Tags: ios, jailbreak

Is there any way to safely jailbreak an iDevice having the iOS 5.0.1 on it? I know a jailbreak is never going to be 100% trustworthy but there's a certain level of acceptance when some experienced users try it and those who are not, can go give it a shot.
Thank you.

Comment: The net is littered with guides and information. Please refer to http://blog.iphone-dev.org/ for an answer to your specific question. The hackers responsible for jailbreaking iOS are white hat and their work is meant to liberate Apple device users, not harm them. They are most certainly 100% trustworthy. While jailbreaking may introduce additional bugs to the system, it does not include nefarious code that may compromise your privacy or security.

Comment: I didn't mean to disrespect you guys. I was precisely talking about bugs that might appear due to _mistesting_. Anyway, I appreciate the link.

Comment: Don't worry George, it is perhaps I that misinterpreted your choice of wording ("trustworthy"). Typically, while jailbreaks do see bugs out of the gate, they are rather quickly repaired, bringing the level of reliability up to that of an unjailbroken device. That of course only applies to the vanilla jailbreak. Any code you inject later (those requiring mobile substrate, and MS itself) are however not covered under that assessment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that a jailbreak has been developed for [non-A5 iDevices](http://www.macrumors.com/2011/12/27/untethered-ios-5-0-1-jailbreak-available-for-non-a5-devices/) running iOS 5.0.1, but no jailbreak yet exists for the iPad 2 and iPhone 4S, which use the A5 chip.

Note that this is a rather localized answer; it seems quite likely that a jailbreak will eventually be developed, but as of January 2, 2012, this seems to be the state of things.